# Cutting stock problem upper bound with gilmore and gomory

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, upper-bound

I am trying to implement this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.04897.pdf (the article is there only for information, no need to read it to answer my question)

At some point they say when talking about a 1 dimensional cutting stock problem $I_R$:

First, we obtain a solution $S$ of the instance $I_R$. For instance, we may round the solution of the linear program introduced by Gilmore and Gomory, and get a solution with at most OPT($I_R$) + $\sigma$ bins. (the gilmore and gomory article [https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~rgomory/academic_papers/24_LP.pdf](https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Ergomory/academic_papers/24_LP.pdf))

Where $\sigma$ is the number of different cutting sizes, and $I_R$ is an instance of the cutting stock problem. (The word bin is used because the initial problem is a bin packing problem that is converted with rounding to a simpler cutting stock problem)

My question is the following; what do they mean with "rounding a solution of the linear program".

- Does this mean that I should simply solve the linear relaxation of the LP introduced by gilmore and gomory and round it to the nearest integer ? I doubt that is the case as the upper bound given is then quite useless since I then know that $S \leq$OPT($I_R$).
- Or does this mean that I should perform column generation and then solve the integer program with the generated columns without performing branch and bound.
- Or is it even something else that I did not get.

Comment: As I understand it (without reading the paper), it is your first choice, but instead of rounding to the nearest integer, you round up to get a feasible solution. This would explain the $+ \sigma$ in the cost of the solution.

Comment: @Guyslain thank you for the clarification, that indeed makes more sense